# Using very small numbers in php define

Tags: php

I am using PHP 5.6.14.

I have three defines:

```
define('rx', -0.000000728190149);
define('ry', -0.00000119748979); 
define('rz', −0.00000408261601);
```

The *last* one gives a parse error:

> syntax error, unexpected T_DNUMBER

I started off with

```
define('rx', -7.28190149E-7); //etc
```

but this gave an unexpected string.

Do I need to go back to using variables? Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: What's the exact error you have ?

Comment: − (U+2212) is not a - (you have a wrong character (minus sign) at the third line)

Comment: Thanks, Timurib. I had looked at that for hours! Problem solved. Any thoughts on using the exponent? (I will check the minus signs!)

Comment: Problem with using exponent in define also vanished when I used a correct minus sign. Great help. Thanks.

Comment: Just realised that I copied these numbers from a text document (to avoid typing errors). Take care when copying over minus signs from text!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your third `define` uses a Unicode `MINUS SIGN` (codepoint 0x2212) instead of a regular `HYPHEN-MINUS` (codepoint 0x2d).

Change it from

```
define('rz', −0.00000408261601);
```

to

```
define('rz', -0.00000408261601);
```